# How to find and filter in nested array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Can someone please explain me how this query works?

Because I'm trying to find only one **locationSpecifications** where is **"code.defaultValue": "LS1"** .. but in result is still more than this.

What am I doing wrong?

**Here is example:** https://mongoplayground.net/p/Zbh9xQ3Fq_w

Thank for help.

**DATA:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "locations": [
      {
        "code": {
          "defaultValue": "IL1"
        },
        "locationSpecifications": [
          {
            "code": {
              "defaultValue": "LS1"
            },
            "minimumCount": {
              "defaultValue": "0"
            }
          },
          {
            "code": {
              "defaultValue": "LS2"
            },
            "minimumCount": {
              "defaultValue": "1"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**QUERY:**

```
db.collection.find({
  "_id": 1,
  locations: {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "code.defaultValue": "IL1",
      locationSpecifications: {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "code.defaultValue": "LS1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**RESULT**

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "locations": [
      {
        "code": {
          "defaultValue": "IL1"
        },
        "locationSpecifications": [
          {
            "code": {
              "defaultValue": "LS1"
            },
            "minimumCount": {
              "defaultValue": "0"
            }
          },
          { // WHY IS HERE ALSO THIS!
            "code": {
              "defaultValue": "LS2"
            },
            "minimumCount": {
              "defaultValue": "1"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Here's the optimized solution just use group and filter operator https://mongoplayground.net/p/nBwlwe9T5ez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query will find the matching document with matching at least 1 element in the array but it will not filter the unmatched element (in the array).

If you want to remove the unmatching element, you need to perform filtering element in the array in the projection.

```
db.collection.find({
  "_id": 1,
  locations: {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "code.defaultValue": "IL1",
      locationSpecifications: {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "code.defaultValue": "LS1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  _id: 1,
  locations: {
    $map: {
      input: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$locations",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.code.defaultValue",
                  "IL1"
                ]
              },
              {
                $in: [
                  "LS1",
                  "$$this.locationSpecifications.code.defaultValue"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      as: "location",
      in: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$location",
          {
            locationSpecifications: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$$location.locationSpecifications",
                cond: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$this.code.defaultValue",
                    "LS1"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G_UCSYrLGZE)

Comment: Thank you Yong Shun , I thought it would be a little easier :) .. Never mind, I'm going to take a better look at those filter functions.